# Expand collapse on html table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, expand

I have an html table. I want to create the expand collapse of the first 3 columns.

Comment: You need something like a tree grid. Take a look at this one: http://www.igniteui.com/tree-grid/balance-sheet

Comment: But the childs are in different columns of the table. Please look at 1st image.

Comment: This was just an example. Top-level items don't necessarily have to have data for those columns and child-level items can have data for columns parent items don't.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using jquery with the following example

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
```

Comment: But how I will move the 2nd and 3rd column under the first one?

Comment: You create child and parent elements via divs or table id